# ¿Cómo crear método genérico para serializar cadena XML en Clase objeto?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación donde obtengo  cadenas con formato XML  entonces debo serializar cada cadena en su respectiva clase.

Lo que deseo es crear un único método en el que pueda serializar estas cadenas con formato xml en su respectiva clase objeto , obviamente pasándole como parámetro el tipo de la clase en la que se va a serializar.

Mi código:

```
public Invoice XML(string xml, out string Error)
    {
        Invoice comprobante = new Invoice();

        Error = "";
        try
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Invoice));
            StringReader sXML = new StringReader(xml);
            comprobante = (Invoice)serializer.Deserialize(sXML);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Error = "Error en la Serialización" + ex.Message;
            comprobante = new Invoice();
        }
        return comprobante;

    }
```

Comment: Y el problema cual seria?

Comment: El problema es que tengo que crear un metodo para cada clase ...por ejemplo en el post expongo el metodo para la clase Invoice...pero nesecito un metodo que lo haga para cualquier clase que pase como parametro...por eso hablo de un metodo generico

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu metodo generico quedaria asi:

```
        public T Xml<T>(string xml, out string Error) where T : new()
        {
            T comprobante = new T();

            Error = "";
            try
            {
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                StringReader sXML = new StringReader(xml);
                comprobante = (T)serializer.Deserialize(sXML);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Error = "Error en la Serialización" + ex.Message;
                comprobante = new T();
            }
            return comprobante;

         }
```

Necesita el constraint new() que indica que la clase debe tener un constructor por defecto:

```
public T Xml<T>(string xml, out string Error) where T : new()
```